# Adding font-weight to figcaption programmatically

Tags: asp.net

How can I add font-weight as bold to `<figcaption>` programmatically?

This I have tried:

```
HtmlGenericControl figCap = new HtmlGenericControl("figcaption");
figCap.Attributes.Add("font-weight", "bold");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold")`, as `.Attributes.Add("font-weight", "bold")` will just create `<figcaption font_weight="bold">...`.